# How to append multiple items to a list with user input without overriding items already in list?

Tags: python-3.x

When I want to append a value to a list, the previous value gets replaced with the new value. I don't want that. Here's my code:

```
a_list = []
i = input("insert item: ")

a_list.append(i)
print(a_list)
```

When I run the code:

```
>>> Insert item: "1"
a_list = ['1']
>>> Insert item: "2"
a_list = ['2']
>>> Insert item: "3"
a_list = ['3']
```

But I want it to output:

```
>>> Insert item: "1"
a_list = ['1']
>>> Insert item: "2"
a_list = ['1','2']
>>> Insert item: "3"
a_list = ['1','2','3']
```

Comment: Python only works one way, you get the output and the application ends. Re-running the application will provide you with a set of new empty list and results. If you want to store information in your list, you should have them saved in a file and imported when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might be creating the list again and again which could be leading to this problem.

```
a_list = []

while(True):

    i = input("Insert item: , Enter 0 to exit")
    if i == 0:
        break
    a_list.append(i)

    print(a_list)

print("a_list = %s" %(a_list))
```

Output:

```
Insert item: , Enter 0 to exit1
[1]
Insert item: , Enter 0 to exit2
[1, 2]
Insert item: , Enter 0 to exit3
[1, 2, 3]
Insert item: , Enter 0 to exit4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Insert item: , Enter 0 to exit5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Insert item: , Enter 0 to exit0
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```